# How to slice mesh

Tags: modifiers

I have my mesh and i want my top red mark part to be slice so that i can get a curve shape as seen from front view. How to delete the below part which is mark in yellow. With simple and clean method. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

[image]

**Front view**
Delete the yellow part

[image]